# Python - Subtracting a specific date-time from current GMT date-time

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

I'm trying to do some time math, but I'm not sure how I could do this. I'd like to subtract a specific date & time I have in a string (e.g.: 15:54:00 2017-5-20) from current GMT time (e.g: 20:06:27 2017-12-22).

Any thoughts on how I could do this?

```
# import data into Python
with open(output_file2) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    d = list(reader)
# here, objects [0][4] and [0][5] would be, for instance: 15:54:00 and 2017-5-20
# , respectively

# UTC Time
os.system("date -u \"+%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d\" | gawk '{print \"  UTC Date & Time:  \", $1, \"\", $2}'")
# eg.: 20:06:27 2017-12-22
```

Any thoughts would be great! Thanks =)

Update: I've tried so far:

```
UTC_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%H:%M:%S  %Y-%m-%d")
print '  UTC Date & Time:  ', UTC_time

time1 = d[0][4]
date1 = d[0][5]
mytime = time1, date1
time_difference = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - mytime
print "HELLO", time_difference
```

but I keep getting an error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'tuple'

Not sure what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Have you tried anything? This sounds like a pretty standard use of [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Comment: Hi glibdude, yeah... I did. Using the command:

Comment: see updated comment above. Still not sure what is going on...

Answer (score 0):

Your `mytime` variable is not a datetime.datetime object and cannot be used to operate against one.  Instead of `mytime = time1, date1` you are looking for something more along the lines of

```
my_date_str = "{} {}".format(time1, date1)
mytime = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_date_str, "%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d")
```

Do realize that in spite of using `utcnow()` the resulting datetime.datetime object is NOT timezone aware, and neither is `mytime`.  So any math between the two is pure clock math, no timezones taken into account.

If you require timezone support, look into [pytz](https://github.com/newvem/pytz) or [Pendulum](https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum) or perhaps find another if they don't suit you.